# Error in codeigniter while file uploading

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

I have a problem while uploading the file this is the whole controller code:
[Controller screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrkwF.png)
and this is the file upload code:

```html
    $config['upload_path'] = './_uploads';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
 
  $this->load->library('Upload');
  $this->upload->initialize($config);
 
  if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
   echo "failed";
  
  } else {
   echo "sucess";
  }
```

And when I run this it gives me error:

```html
An Error Was Encountered
Resource 'upload' already exists and is not a CI_Upload instance
```

Comment: Add complete code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using this code for multiple image upload? If you are using for multiple image then please load upload library `$this->load->library('upload')` outside loop.

Please provide full code with method name if not multiple images.

Comment: No it is just a single file upload

Comment: I add the whole controller code on the original post could please check it once @Danish Ali

Answer (score 2):

You are loading 'Upload' instead of 'upload' (upload should be in small case). and I also would like to make little more changes

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './_uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = 'filename.png'; //extension should be same as uploaded file

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
        echo "failed";

    } else {
        echo "sucess";
    }
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: The problem is with uploading the library I tried many different ways but nothing changed

Comment: Can you print error by function: print_r($this->upload->display_errors()); so I can have better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The upload class must have been autoloaded already on your config /autoload.php so reinitializing the upload class will throw an error.